# assigning values separated by a comma in a column to different columns using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, pycharm

In the original dataframe, there is a column named 'NVE Liste' and only has one row. In that column, the values are
'0034104060001008405,00341040600001008498,00341040600002187444,00341040600002187505,00341040600002187512,00341040600002190079,00341040600002190093,00341040600002196880,00341040600012187434,00341040600012187496'. Now firstly i want to split every number separted by comma in a different column. for example, the first number should be in column named 'NVE1', the second number should be in column named 'NVE2' and so on, in the new dataframe.

how can i achieve this any help would be appreciated

i tried using str.split, also tried different methods but it ended up not making new columns it just made an extra with same values

Comment: I suggest rather loading your data from CSV into Pandas using whatever loading tool is available for CSV.

Comment: i have used pandas to load the file and assigned each value from the original dataframe to the new dataframe. i am only stuck on this

Comment: Do you have any code to provide as a minimal reproducible example (MRE)? That'd greatly help in trying to see what goes wrong and where. Asking because I was going to suggest a CSV reader until I read the previous comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it the same way you would add a calculated column but use str.split(',').  Here is one way it could be accomplished using the sample data you provided.

```
import pandas as pd

#Create a sample dataframe per the OP question
entrylist=[]
OriginalDF=pd.DataFrame(columns = [['NVEListe']])
#You can add more entries than just one to the list if you want a better example
entrylist.append('0034104060001008405,00341040600001008498,00341040600002187444,00341040600002187505,00341040600002187512,00341040600002190079,00341040600002190093,00341040600002196880,00341040600012187434,00341040600012187496')

OriginalDF.loc[0]=entrylist
print('This is the original DataFrame')
display(OriginalDF)

#split the original entry using the comma separator
splitentry=(OriginalDF.iloc[0]['NVEListe']).split(',')

#Make a list of names for the new columns
NewColumnlst=[]
for i in range(len(splitentry)):
    NewColumnlst.append('NVEListe'+str(i+1))

#Split the string and add to new columns
for i in range(len(splitentry)):
    OriginalDF[NewColumnlst[i]]=splitentry[i]

#Drop the unsplit original column
OriginalDF.drop('NVEListe', axis=1, inplace=True)


print('This is the new DataFrame showing the split columns')
display(OriginalDF)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(['001,002,003'], columns=['NVE Liste'])
```

df

```
    NVE Liste
0   001,002,003
```

**Code**

use `str.split`

```
out = (df['NVE Liste'].str.split(',', expand=True)
       .rename(lambda x: f'NVE{x + 1}', axis=1)
)
```

out:

```
    NVE1    NVE2    NVE3
0   001     002     003
```

If you want to create a column in `df`, concat `df` & `out`.

```
out2 = pd.concat([df, out], axis=1)
```

out2

```
    NVE Liste   NVE1    NVE2    NVE3
0   001,002,003 001     002     003
```